# Our dog accidentally ate pimobendan

Tags: dogs, safety, medicines

We have a dog who is on pimobendan, and our other dog who weighs about 13 pounds (5.9 kg) accidentally got 0.625 mg of it.

Will he be okay?

Comment: you need to call your vet about this,heart medication might be dangerous.wellcome to pets.se.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always call your vet as soon as possible when something like this happens. By the time someone on the internet answers, if it was a problem it will likely have resulted in serious effect by now.

That being said, 0.625 mg of pimobendan is even a low dose for a 13 lb dog (roughly 0.1 mg/kg). Typical therapeutic doses range from 0.2 to 0.5 mg/kg per day (per *Plumbs Veterinary Drugs*).

Toxicity is therefore not a concern at such low dose.

In all likelihood, it will not be a problem. Pimobendan works to increase heart contractility, and in a healthy dog a single low dose will not be a problem. The concern comes if your dog has heart disease or other conditions which may make reaction to the drug less predictable.

Close monitoring for 24 hours is a reasonable option in such a case; if any doubts or concerns then immediate evaluation by a veterinarian is needed.

Answer (score 1):

And to add to the other experiences, I was preparing a pill pocket to give our 45 lb Border Collie her 5 mg of Vetmedin (pimobendan) when I turned back and the pill was gone.  I could only assume I knocked it off the counter where it was probably eaten by our 21 lb Cavalon (aka "The Vacuum Cleaner").  Called the ASPCA Poison Control Center (888-426-4435) where they told me the same thing:  monitor for two hours for signs of vomiting, diarrhea, etc., etc.  Two hours later, our dog seems fine.  One interesting thing I found out was that, because we have the Home Again microchip, we were not charged for the consultation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone, and saves them $75.
**My dog weighing 12 pounds (5.4 kg), swallowed (stole my other dog's) pill, which was dosed at 1.25 mg of pimobendan.**  I called poison control, paid 75 dollars for a "calculation;" the results are as follows:

*At that low dose, there is a slight chance for poisoning. Monitor the following for 2 hours: vomiting, diarrhea, decrease in activity, wobbly walking, and the dog's gums to be white.  If any of these symptoms occur, go to an emergency vet immediately.*

After two hours, the possibility of poisoning is reduced further, and you no longer need to monitor the dog.

Answer (score -1):

I want to thank the ifo given by last comment regarding 12 pd dog and the results from the 75.00 call. You helped ease my mind. I thought it was our other dogs (whom has recently passed vitamins. I did not find out till today it was not it was pimeobendan.. yes I felt like i may of killed my 12 pound lil morkie. That was at least 26 hours prior. I knew my other dog had vitamins so when i seen prescrion type bottles i knew those were for his heart but .. not blaming just explaining. Idiot me started making homemade dog food  so i took one crushed it and sprinkled on her food bowl. Shes a bit lethargic today but not so much exibiting any red flags just not her normal hyperself. I hope she will be ok. I mean other than that she is not concerned for eating and thats a bit concerning. I feel like my idiocity caused her undue pain. Had that med showed the label with the real name i would never given her that the label was and came all stuck togethrr reaveiling the name vetamed and i thought vetamed was the vet advised vitamins.i just wanted to ensure she was getting adiquent vitimes with homemade food

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32073)

Comment: You can also leave a comment or edit your post to say thank you or to add more information :)